# How do I get my home made iPhone apps on my phone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am a beginner Xcode iOS app devoloper and i really want to put my apps on my iPhone. I have tried exporting the application and putting it in iTunes to install on my phone, but that doesn't work. I have done some research and it seems like the only way to do this is my enrolling in the apple developer program witch cost $99/year. But i don't have the money. Can someone please help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do it is join the iOS Developer Program (pay for the account), or find a friend with an account to let you mooch off of theirs.

Comment: damn i'm the only iOS nerd person i know

Comment: save up then.  Please mark my answer accepted.

Comment: The iOS Developer costs < 100$ a year, so if you have no iOS friends, ask regular friends to sponsor you. You can make a deal to give them free promo codes for every app you create for example.

Comment: thats actually not a bad idea Joride

Answer (score 0):

Steps to run app from Xcode in device:

1. Create a developer account on apple.
2. Then add certificate in it.
3. Then add your device UUID.
4. Make a provisioning profile and add your device in this.
5. Download the certificate and provisioning profile.
6. Now connect your iPhone to mac through cable, change the simulator to iOS device and 
        as your device is connected it shows your device's Name.
7. Now go to build settings and add the provisioning profile which you downloaded and you are 
         done.
8. Simply run the project.

If you have an ipa you can simply use itunes, drag the app in itune's app section and install in iPhone.